# Spark: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Am not sure what's causing this exception running my Spark job after running for some few hours.

Am running Spark 2.0.2

Any debugging tip ?

```
2016-12-27 03:11:22,199 [shuffle-server-3] ERROR org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler - Error while invoking RpcHandler#receive() for one-way message.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not find CoarseGrainedScheduler.
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postMessage(Dispatcher.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Dispatcher.postOneWayMessage(Dispatcher.scala:134)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcHandler.receive(NettyRpcEnv.scala:571)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.processOneWayMessage(TransportRequestHandler.java:180)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportRequestHandler.handle(TransportRequestHandler.java:109)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:119)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEve
```

Comment: `--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false` is what fixed this issue for me. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It's not necessary to disable dynamic allocation at all. Obviously the dynamic allocation contains some routines for "dynamic *de*allocation". In your case the executors kill earlier then it's needed. You can just increase the `spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout` config to fix this. So the executors won't being destroying so aggressively.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yeah now I know the meaning of that cryptic exception, the executor got killed because it exceeds the container memory threshold. 
There are couple of reasons that could happen but the first culprit is to check your job (e.g. repartition) or try adding more nodes/executors to your cluster.

Comment: What are those couple of reasons? What if I am okay with the jobs running slow, without increasing the nodes/resources? Can you give a more elaborate explanation, maybe share the link to a reference?

Comment: @AnkitKhettry it still depends on the size of your data and how much memory the executor requires to process it. If the memory usage exceeds the executor-memory, your container gets killed and you get that error message.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't a good answer, especially for a question that comes up in the first page of Google results. "Check your job" for what? As it turned out, this exception was a red herring; as *Tomer* said, the real exception was higher in the log.

Comment: how do you know is  "the executor got killed because it exceeds the container memory threshold"

Answer (score 18):

Basically it means that there is another reason for the failure.
Try to find other exception in your job logs.

See "Exceptions" sections here:
https://medium.com/@wx.london.cun/spark-on-yarn-f74e82ab6070

Answer (score 6):

It could be a resource problem. Try to increase the number of cores and executor and also to assign more RAM to the application then you should increase the partition number of your RDD by calling a repartition. The ideal number of partitions depends on previous settings. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another silly reason could be that your time in spark streaming awaitTermination is set to much less time, and it got terminated before completing

```
ssc.awaitTermination(timeout)
@param timeout: time to wait in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this has happened when I specified a path that doesn't exist for a `spark.read.load`  Or if I specify the wrong format for input ie `parquet` instead of `csv`.

Unfortunately, the actual error sometime is silent and happens above the stack trace.  Sometimes though you can find another set of stack traces along with this one that will be more meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

This error seems to be a bug in Spark Core and was fixed in Spark 3.2.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-22769

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was caused by usage of the same query name and/or the same checkpoint location path by the several different queries. They were created in the loop based on the iterated collection, but all them were using the same query name and checkpoint location.

Please check logs for  something like that:

```
2021-12-01 15:05:46,906 WARN  [main] streaming.StreamingQueryManager (Logging.scala:logWarning(69)) - Stopping existing streaming query [id=b13a69d7-5a2f-461e-91a7-a9138c4aa716, runId=9cb31852-d276-42d8-ade6-9839fa97f85c], as a new run is being started.
```